# Animate the border circle clockwise on click

Tags: javascript, css

I have created a heart icon using svg which is being filled on click, what I also want to do is show an circle animation outside of heart being created clockwise. Currently the circle just rotates as shown in the code below:

```js
  Array.from(document.querySelectorAll(".heart")).forEach(button => button.addEventListener('click', function () {
    if (button.closest(".circle").style.visibility == "visible") {
      console.log("In if condition");
      button.closest(".circle").style.visibility = 'hidden';
    }
    else {
      console.log("In else condition");
      button.closest(".circle").style.visibility = 'visible';
    }
    button.classList.toggle("heart-fill-up");

  }))
```

```css
  .circle {
    visibility: hidden;
    margin: 100px auto;
    position: relative;
    overflow: hidden;
    width: 107px;
    height: 100px;
    border-radius: 50%;
    box-shadow: 0 0 0 3px red;
  }

  .circle:hover {
    animation: border 1s forwards;
  }

  @keyframes border {
    0% {
      visibility: hidden;
      transform: rotate(0deg);
    }

    100% {
      visibility: visible;
      transform: rotate(360deg);
    }
  }

  svg {
    max-height: 120px;
  }

  .heart {
    fill: transparent;
    transition: all .5s;
  }

  .heart-fill-up {
    fill: red;
    border: 50px solid blue;
  }

  .lines {
    display: none;
  }

  .lines-show {
    fill: red;
  }
```

```html
<html>

<head>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/5.11.2/css/all.css">
</head>
<div class="circle">
  <svg style="visibility: visible;" version="1.1" id="Layer_1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"
    xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" x="0px" y="0px" viewBox="0 0 298 281"
    style="enable-background:new 0 0 298 281;" xml:space="preserve">
    <style type="text/css">
      .heart {
        stroke: #FF0606;
        stroke-miterlimit: 10;
        stroke-width: 5px;
      }
    </style>
    <title>icon_wishlist</title>
    <g id="icon_wishlist">
      <path class="heart" d="M66.3,69.4c-19.1,20-19.1,51.5,0,71.5l84.6,87.9l84.7-87.8c19.1-20,19.1-51.5,0-71.5
  c-18-19.1-48.1-19.9-67.2-1.8c-0.6,0.6-1.2,1.2-1.8,1.8L151,85.7l-15.6-16.2c-18-19.1-48.1-19.9-67.2-1.8
  C67.6,68.2,67,68.8,66.3,69.4L66.3,69.4z" />
    </g>
  </svg>
</div>
<style>

</style>
<script>

</script>

</html>
```

I want the circle to be shown being created from top right to the top left, creating a full circle on click. I don't want the heart to rotate.
Any help is appreciated! 
Thanks in advance!

Comment: while this doesn't answer your question, it might be beneficial for you to use a 3rd party package like VIVUS for the desired outcome.
https://maxwellito.github.io/vivus/

Comment: What you want is an arc that grows from 0 to 360 degrees?

Comment: I don't want to use any third party packages for this thing @adnantariq

Comment: Yeah something like that, just to add an extra animation to the click outside of the heart @JDunken

Comment: Well then you don't want to draw a circle, you want to draw an arc, with the keyframes defining the angle of the arc, and don't forget you can use negative angles to draw in the opposite direction.

Comment: Well you can call it an arc or a circle but that's the animation I want to do, and I don't want to do opposite direction, that's why I've mentioned I want the animation clockwise.

Answer (score 2):

Why not use an SVG `circle` and animate the `stroke-dash-offset`

```css
circle {
  stroke: red;
  stroke-width: 1;
  fill: pink;
  stroke-dasharray: 1;
  stroke-dashoffset: 1;
  animation: dash 2s linear infinite;
}

@keyframes dash {
  from {
    stroke-dashoffset: 1;
  }
  to {
    stroke-dashoffset: 0;
  }
}

svg {
  height: 90vh;
  display: block;
  transform: rotate(-90deg);
  margin: auto;
}
```

```html
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" viewbox="0 0 100 100">

    <circle cx="50" cy="50" r="40" pathLength="1"/>

</svg>
```

Comment: How can I put the heart icon in it and make the circle animation only on click of the heart?